# Django (REST framework): How to censor columns when user is not logged in

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django as my CMS and React for my Frontend.
For the API I am using Django REST framework.

In Django I have a model like this:

```
class person(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

I would like to censor some columns depending on if the user sent me the correct Authentification Token or not.

So in result I would like to have something like

```
{ "number": 1, "name": "johnny", "last_name": "miagi"}
```

when the user is authentificated, and

```
{ "number": 1, "name": "johnny", "last_name": "########"}
```

when not.

Is this possible? I am, unfortunately, a beginner in Django. I know about the user privileges system, but as far as I know this is meant to be used on complete tables, not columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can censor fields by your own by modifying the serializer this way:

```py
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    last_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_last_name')

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('__all__')

    def get_last_name(self, obj):
        request = getattr(self.context, 'request', None)
        if not request.user:
            return "########"
```

By using this, you can also do user-level censors to `last_name` field by putting conditional statements in your `get_last_name()` method.

Answer (score 1):

make 2 serializers or in serializer make a condition when user loged in then use one serializer else use another serializer.

```
    class ModelApiView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        """
        List of User Model History api
        """


        def get_serializer_class(self):
            if self.request.user is None or self.request.user is Anonymous:
                return serializer_one
            else:
                return serializer_two
        queryset = Model.objects.all()

class serializer_two(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = "__all__"

class serializer_one(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    field_value = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_field_value')

    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ('__all__')

    def get_field_value(self, obj):
        return "########"
```